# TYPO3 11 set custom page title h1 html

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I have TYPO3 11.
I created a Page Title Provider

```php
<?php
    
declare(strict_types=1);
    
namespace Myvendor\modellobando\Seo;
    
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\PageTitle\AbstractPageTitleProvider;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
    
class BandoTitleProvider extends AbstractPageTitleProvider
{
    private const DEFAULT_PROPERTIES = 'title';
    private const DEFAULT_GLUE = '" "';
    
    public function setTitle(string $title): void
    {
        $this->title = "ecco ".$title;
    }
}
```

I defined it in `template.setup`

```
config.pageTitleProviders {
    record {
        provider = Goproject\modellobando\Seo\BandoTitleProvider
    }
}
```

It works with meta tag title but the data of the page is not changed, I have to set the tag `h1` in html in my layout, how can I do that?

---

**updated question**:

As I wrote in comment I tried a query to get info about my model but I don't know how avoid SQL injection using query string parameter (GET) like `uid=12`

```
page.10 {
    dataProcessing {
        1001 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
        1001 {
            table=mytable
            pidInList = 16
            markers.uid.field = uid
            as = datainfobando
            where = (uid = ???)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The PageTitleProvider is only for the meta tags, has nothing to do with the output of your HTML body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `h1` tag means you are in the body of the HTML document. That content does not have an automated content.
But you can insert it in your page template. If you want it set everywhere you can use the page layout template. You only have to provide the information to your FLUID page template, which can be done easily in typoscript.

---

Avoiding SQL-injection within a `select` can be done with using [markers](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/Functions/Select.html#markers) and securing them.
Eg. reducing them to integer values.

```
1001 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
1001 {
   table=mytable
   pidInList = 16
   where = {#uid} = ###recordId### 
   as = datainfobando

   markers {
      recordId.data = GP:myId
      recordId.intval = 1
   }
}
```

Comment: ok, i think i have to do a query to database, i have a custom table,  i tried some code but i don't know how to use query string parameters and avoid sql injection. i write the code here below as an answer.

Comment: don't add additional information as answers but edit your question and append it.